# How to print ClosedRange in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm learning Kotlin , and I'm trying to undetstand `Ranges`

I created a range of `String` as follows

```
val alpha = "A".."Z"
```

I want to print this for that I wrote

```
for (item in alpha) println(item)
```

But it gives the error

> Error:(13, 18) Kotlin: For-loop range must have an 'iterator()' method

Can anyone help, how to print this range?

Comment: What does it mean to have a closed range of strings?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you can't do it with `String`s by default, since there's no `iterator()` for `ClosedRange<String>`, but `Char`s will work directly:

```
val r = 'A'..'Z'
r.forEach(::println)
```

It will be of type `CharRange` and provide the needed `iterator()`.

To make your very special example work with `String`s, you could define your own extension function and delegate to a `Iterator<Char>`:

```
operator fun ClosedRange<String>.iterator(): Iterator<String> {
    val charIt = (start.toCharArray().first()..endInclusive.toCharArray().first()).iterator()

    return object : Iterator<String> {
        override fun hasNext() = charIt.hasNext()
        override fun next(): String = charIt.nextChar().toString()
    }
}
```

Now it works as you wished. But be aware that this does not make sense for most use cases with ranges of `String`.

Answer (score 1):

```
val alpha = "A".."Z"
```

This is a plain *range*, which means it's an abstract representation of a contiguous subset within a total order. The only operation such an entity supports is answering the question "is this element within this range?", and it will be based purely on the contract of `Comparable<T>`.

In your case, consider a string like `"THREAD"`. Does it belong to your range? It sorts higher than `"A"` but lower than `"Z"`, so it does belong to it. But you probably didn't intend to iterate over it, or the infinity of all other strings belonging to your range.

What you considered as a given is actually a special case: *iterable ranges*. They are defined only on the three types representing integral types: `IntRange`, `LongRange` and `CharRange`. These are the types where the subset belonging to the range can actually be enumerated and iterated over.

Answer (score 1):

I Loved The answers of @s1m0nw1 and @Marko Topolnik. 
***You can't really iterate over a ClosedRange<String>.***

The literal may mislead us to think it's a ClosedRange<Char>

```
var range = "A".."C" // misleading literal
```

What you CAN do:
Just a small addition: is to map the characters to Strings

```
val r = ('A'..'Z').map { it.toString() }//.forEach(::println)
for (letter in r){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to print this range?

I think the only way to print this range is

```
println(alpha)
```

And you'll get

```
A..Z
```

This is how to "print" this range.

You're trying to travel through a non-iterable range, this is invalid.
Like, you cannot `for (i in File("a.txt")..File("Main.java")) println(i)`.

Answer (score 0):

Can You Try This May Help You, I think you actually want 'A'..'Z' not "A".."Z"

```
var A = 'A'..'Z'
for(value in A){
    println("$value")
}
```