# Use Array<String> in a Flux

Tags: spring, kotlin, range, reactive-programming

Could you guys help me out with using Array and stream (?) over it to use single element (String) to save Movie to db and return FLux. Spring specific stuff isn't important - just the way to iterate over alphabet and create random Movies. What's the best and most-kotlinish way of doing this?

```
    val alphabet = arrayOf("A".."Z")
    val exampleMovies: Flux<Movie> = Flux.just(alphabet)
            .flatMap { movieRepository.save(Movie(name = it)) }
```

I'm getting compilation error:

```
Error:(15, 62) Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is Array<ClosedRange<String>>! but String? was expected
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `arrayOf("A".."Z")` will give an `Array<ClosedRange<String>>`, i.e. the array has one element of type `ClosedRange`. What you actually wanted to have is an `Array<String>` with elements `A, B, C, ..., Z` I guess? Unfortunately, the range operator doesn't work like this for `Strings`, explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49023846/8073652).

Instead, create that array by mapping a `CharRange` accordingly:

```
val alphabet = ('A'..'Z').map(Char::toString).toTypedArray()
```

Comment: You can also just use a `List` and substitute `Flux.just()` with `Flux.fromIterable()`.